# Mysql : select aggregated values in between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got mysql query (generated by zf2), it looks like

````
SELECT `subt`.`from` AS `from`, SUM(ordered) AS `sum_ordered`, 
SUM(income) AS `sum_income`, SUM(sales_by_payment) AS 
`sum_sales_by_payment`
FROM (
SELECT `w`.`brand` AS `brand`, `w`.`article` AS `article`, 
`w`.`subject` AS `subject`, `w`.`size` AS `size`, `w`.`from` AS             
`from`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(income,0)) AS `income`) AS `income`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(income_sum_price,0)) AS `income_sum_price`) AS 
`income_sum_price`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(ordered,0)) AS `ordered`) AS `ordered`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(ordered_sum_price,0)) AS `ordered_sum_price`) AS 
`ordered_sum_price`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(ordered_max_by_day,0)) AS `ordered_max_by_day`) AS 
`ordered_max_by_day`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(return_before_payment,0)) AS 
`return_before_payment`) AS `return_before_payment`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(return_before_payment_sum_price,0)) AS 
`return_before_payment_sum_price`) AS 
`return_before_payment_sum_price`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(sales_by_payment,0)) AS `sales_by_payment`) AS 
`sales_by_payment`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(sales_by_payment_sum_price,0)) AS 
`sales_by_payment_sum_price`) AS `sales_by_payment_sum_price`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(`return`,0)) AS ```return```) AS `return`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(`return_sum_price`,0)) AS ```return_sum_price```) 
AS `return_sum_price`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(`stock`,0)) AS ```stock```) AS `stock`, (
SELECT SUM(IF (sales_by_payment IS NOT NULL, 
sales_by_payment_sum_price / sales_by_payment, NULL)) AS 
`sale_price`) AS `sale_price`, (
SELECT SUM(income_sum_price * 0.62) AS `our_percent`) AS 
`our_percent`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(income_sum_price,0) * 0.25) AS 
`cost_price_income`) AS `cost_price_select`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(sales_by_payment_sum_price,0) - 
(IFNULL(income_sum_price,0) * 0.25)) AS `profit`) AS `profit`, (
 SELECT SUM(IF(income IS NOT NULL, (sales_by_payment / income) * 
 100, 0)) AS `sales_from_income`) AS `sales_from_income`, (
 SELECT (SUM(sales_by_payment) / SUM(return_before_payment)) * 100 AS 
 `returns_buyout`) AS `returns_buyout`, (
 SELECT SUM(return_before_payment) / SUM(ordered) * 100 AS `returns`) AS 
`returns`, (
SELECT SUM(sales_by_payment) / SUM(ordered) * 100 AS `buyout`) AS 
`buyout`, (
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(income,0) - IFNULL(sales_by_payment,0) + 
IFNULL(`return`,0)) AS `total`) AS `total`, (
SELECT (SUM(IFNULL(income,0)) - SUM(IFNULL(stock,0)) - 
SUM(IFNULL(`sales_by_payment`,0)) + SUM(IFNULL(`return`,0))) AS 
`in_the_way`) AS `in_the_way`
FROM `wildberries` AS `w`
WHERE `from` >= '2016-02-01' AND `end` <= '2017-05-04'
GROUP BY `article`
ORDER BY `article` DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0) AS `subt`
GROUP BY DAY(`from`)
ORDER BY `from` ASC
````

If dates range are between one year, all works fine. But if i use different years, it returns only one row.
Could anyone give me advice - why is it happen and how should i modify query?

Table scheme is

```
CREATE TABLE `wildberries` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`brand` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`subject` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`article` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`size` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`income` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`income_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ordered` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ordered_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ordered_max_by_day` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`return_before_payment` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`return_before_payment_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`sales_by_payment` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`sales_by_payment_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`return` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`return_sum_price` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`stock` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`source_file` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`from` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`end` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `article` (`article`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Your query is wrong and/or impossible to analyse. For instance there's no closing parenthesis for the main nested subquery coming after this : `sum_sales_by_payment
FROM (`

Comment: Pls see the following guidance on how to ask good sql related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That's the ugliest sql statement I have ever seen.

Comment: You say this statement got generated by zf2? It is not only horrible to read, but even invalid. (`(SELECT SUM(ifnull(income,0) ) AS income) AS income` can better be written as `COALESCE(SUM(income),0)` (or `IFNULL(SUM(income),0)`) for instance. And as mentioned in my answer, the aggregation violates the SQL standard.)

Answer (score 0):

In your subquery you group by column `article`, but you select column `from`. You don't tell the DBMS which of the article's froms you want to see. This is invalid according to the SQL standard, but MySQL lets this slip and gives you one of the article's froms arbitrarily chosen.

So for the first 20 articles you select rather random dates.

In your main query you group by these dates' days parts. This can result in 1 to 20 rows and is based on coincidence (i.e. how the records happen to be stored on disk at that moment and how the DBMS retrieves them).